# Code stops working after first run

Tags: lua

Hello stack overflow users, I have some code here:

```
local input = nil
print("What file do you want to access?")
input = io.read();
local file = io.open(input, "r")

function infiniteLoop()
  print("What do you want to know more about?")
  input = io.read();
  while true do
    line = file:read()
    if line == nil then break end
        if string.find(line, input) then
        print(line)
     end
  end
end

repeat
  infiniteLoop()
until false
```

As you could guess from the title, it works the first run, but the second time it won't print out what you want, regardless of it being in the file.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Zt9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need reset file pointer. try add `file:seek(0)` in the begining of function